# What is difference between Stardust and Activiti

Tags: eclipse, apache, activiti, bpmn

I'm trying to select an open BPMN tools for my project,
I found Infinity/Stardust from Eclipse and Activiti.

What are the differences/advantages between these BPMN tools ?

Comment: Hi, could you please tell us more on the project, it will be easier to provide usefull information on BPMS. By the way, you may also have a look to Bonita from bonitasoft and JBPM from Jboss. Other tools exists in other languages but I have no feedback.

Comment: Basically integration project, that integrates various legacy and new applications together for one order.

Comment: I was unaware of the Stardust project until I saw this question in the forums. Looking at it's history, it appears to have been a commercial product Carnot -> Sunguard Infinity Process Platform up until very recently. 

Infinity Process Platform, as far as I know, was only ever available as a PAAS offering (someone please correct me if I am wrong) and Carnot only ever managed to gain traction in it's local market of Germany. I wouid question the strength of the community behind Stardust at this time.

Activiti on the other hand has a very strong and vibrant community.

Comment: Activiti is not from Apache, is it Apache Licensed.

Comment: Yes, Activiti is under the Apache license. But it is NOT from Apache

Comment: Stardust is NOT active now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When comparing BPMS one usually needs to consider the particular project requirements and situation. I cannot cover all aspects here, but let me add some thoughts.

A very significant difference between Activiti and Stardust is certainly the size and maturity of the code base. The Stardust code base is more than 5 times the code base of Activiti. Under the hopefully fair assumption that the Stardust team is not coding 5 times less efficiently, Stardust is more feature rich.

Some statistics from Ohloh (@see https://www.ohloh.net/p/eclipse-stardust and https://www.ohloh.net/p/activiti):

> **Activiti** has had **4,388** commits made by **79 contributors** representing **438,155** lines of code
>
> **Stardust** has had **8,312** commits made by **38 contributors** representing **2,538,729** lines of code
>
> **Activiti** took an estimated **116 years** of effort (COCOMO model) starting with its first commit in June, 2010 ending with its most
>   recent commit 3 days ago
>
> **Stardust** took an estimated **726 years** of effort (COCOMO model)  starting with its first commit in December, 2011 ending with its most
>   recent commit 7 days ago
>
> Activiti has a codebase with a **long source history** maintained by a
>   very large development team with **increasing Y-O-Y commits**
>
> Stardust has a young, but **established codebase** maintained by a
>   very large development team with **stable Y-O-Y commits**

Both products originate from the Java world. Activiti seems to keep focusing primarily on the Java community and is sometimes positioned as BPMS for primarily for Java developers. Stardust has invested strongly into interoperability with the .NET world and is also targeting an audience that is not too familiar with Java, for instance with the web modeler. (SunGard has a number of .NET products that it integrates with the commercial Stardust version).

Activiti has a young code base and was designed for BPMN2. Stardust has a 13+ years old code base and is gradually supporting more and more BPMN2 elements.

Greg Harley's comment is not entirely correct.

- there is still a commercial product of Stardust, the Infinity Process Platform (IPP). the code bases are synchronized and merged regularly. Both version have no license fees. Support from SunGard is available for the commercial code base. In terms of functionality and maturity Stardust and IPP are almost equivalent.
- As a startup CARNOT had its primary market in Germany, Austria and Switzerland and additional traction in the Americas. After the acquisition SunGard rebranded CARNOT to Infinity Process Platform. So it has always been available as a standalone product, recently also hosted and as a Paas/Saas offering. In the Gartner Magic Quadrant 2007 SunGard was ranked 2nd in vision with a strong ability to execute. Later SunGard was not included in the Gartner quadrant anymore because SunGard is primarily offering products to the Finanacial Servcies and Energy industry. IPP is embedded in more than 60 SunGard products and has hundreds of installations worldwide.

Activity has a diverse group of committers and an active community. Some strong contributors like the founder and project lead Tom Baeyens or those from Camunda recently left the Community and started/forked new projects.

Stardust was first release in Summer 2013 in the Eclipse Kepler release. Hence so far its community is young and not very divers at this time. There has been significant growth during the last few months though.

Activiti is under the Apache license. Stardust is under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).