# Java BPM Suites - Interoperability with .Net

Tags: java, .net, jbpm, business-process-management

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989093/what-is-difference-between-startdust-and-activity) It states that Stardust has very good interoperability with .Net. I assume when anything is exposed as web services , there is no issues with interoperability. Does Stardust provide integration with native .net libraries? If so is Jboss JBPM provide the same level of support?

Comment: You may also want to consider Bonita BPM. It is also a Java BPM suite that exposes all of its functionalities via REST APIs. This means that it can also be integrated with .Net though not using native .net libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stardust exposes all engine functionality via SOAP (and is adding more and more REST). No native library is provided. It is not required.

- [Stardust Web Service API](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.dev/html/handbooks/programming/embed/pg-webservice-api.html?cp=72_7_2_0_2)
- [Stardust Web Service API classes](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.dev%2Fhtml%2Fhandbooks%2Fprogramming%2Fembed%2Fwebservice%2Fpg-webservice-classes.html)
- [Stardust C# client example](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.dev%2Fhtml%2Fexamples%2Fws-client-c-sharp%2Freadme.html)
- [Stardust UI mashup example for .NET](https://wiki.eclipse.org/STP/Stardust/KnowledgeBase/Integration/UI/UIMashup/VB_NET_Example)
- [Some Stardust WS API examples](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Knowledge_Base/Web_Service_API)
  [- Stardust Process Interface / external invocation via SOAP or REST](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.dev%2Fhtml%2Fhandbooks%2Fprogramming%2Fpg-process-interface-invocation.htm)
- [Stardust Knowledge base](http://wiki.eclipse.org/STP/Stardust/KnowledgeBase)

I cannot comment on jBPM.